# SQL SELECT for a one-to-many feature-relation to select key with certain features

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Assuming I have a table with the following data:

```
foreign-key | feature
          1 | a
          1 | b
          2 | a
          2 | b
          2 | c
          3 | a
          3 | c
```

I want a single statement that returns a unique list of keys that have assigned both feature a and feature b, so the result rows should be "1, 2".

Assuming I'd want to add additional constraints to to the query, it'd be good if the whole thing is not nested into multiple layers.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: I use postgresql.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `group by` and `having`.

```
select foreign-key
from tbl 
where feature in ('a','b')
group by foreign-key
having count(distinct feature)=2
```

Comment: Can the line "where feature in ('a', 'b') also contain "like" statements?

Comment: yes..and the `having count ... ` has to modified accordingly.

Comment: According to the amount of features I am looking for? I was thinking about ```where lower(feature) in (like '%a%', like '%b%')```.

Comment: @salbeira It would be nice if SQL allowed that syntax where you use a LIKE inside an IN.  But have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `GROUP BY` with `MIN/MAX()` :

```
SELECT foreign-key
FROM table t 
WHERE feature IN ('a', 'b')
GROUP BY foreign-key
HAVING MIN(feature) <> MAX(feature);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just offering a more convulted method.

Which uses a CASE WHEN in the COUNT DISTINCT.

But maybe you'll wonder: Is there any benefit to be gained by such a sin against code-golfing?

Well, it makes it simple to swap all those `=` criteria by a `LIKE` criteria.
Or an `ILIKE` criteria (case-Insensitive LIKE).

```
SELECT foreign-key
FROM tbl 
WHERE (feature = 'a' OR feature = 'b')
GROUP BY foreign-key
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT
             CASE 
             WHEN feature = 'a' THEN 1 
             WHEN feature = 'b' THEN 2 
             END) = 2
```